# Error Parsing JSON when trying POST request on Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, spotify

I'm currently developing a web application using JavaScript which the web app will create a new playlist then save it to user's Spotify account. Now, I'm facing the issue of "Error Parsing JSON" whenever I tried POST request. Below is my code:

```js
var urlString = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + userID + '/playlists';

app.createPlaylist = (urlString) => $.ajax({
      url: urlString,
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
      },
      contentType: 'application/json',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: "test",
        public: true
      }),
      dataType: 'json',
});
```

Can anyone tell me what's the problem? I've tried surfing this website, and none of the possible answers to my question helped my situation.

Comment: do you mean besides the JS syntax error in the above code?

Comment: can you change the dataType to `text` then console log the result from Spotify so you can manually look at the response and confirm it is in json format?

Comment: It would be _most_ helpful to fix the syntax error firstl